# Back to previous page in AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, ajax

Acutally I have a working AJAX Call that get me back after succeed to a static defined Site.

```
$.ajax({ 
            url: 'myPage.php',
            type: 'get', 
            data: {TestaufstellungID:TestaufstellungID, Datum: Datum}, 
            dataType: 'text',

            success:function(data){ 

                    window.location = "staticPage.php";
                 console.log('SQL Eintrag Erfolgreich Aktuallisiert');
     },
     error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
         console.log(exception);


            }
        });
```

It works fine with `window.location` but I want a dynamic site, back to this site where the use came from, like in PHP:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Please don't give me answer like `history.go(-1);` becasue I don't want cached sites. Should be do the same like the PHP code, because in some cases I need the page URL with all string (`Get-Method`).

My reference Post, to understand the step by step page working order, I want to be back all in all to the first step (page) but this page is not always the same one.

https://stackoverflow.com/qs/56239790

Comment: Why are you using AJAX at all?

Comment: Thats just one example Ajax Call. I need calls to the server without reloading. And i edit the post with my reference question to understand the Background.

Comment: Are you building a single page application? If yes, you should look into using a client-side router: https://github.com/krasimir/navigo. If not, why are you loading the previous page's html with an ajax call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand you completely. However...

```
$previous = "javascript:history.go(-1)";
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $previous = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

For redirecting with PHP

```
header("Location: $previous");
```

For testing with a HTML link

```
<a href="<?= $previous ?>">Back</a>
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To Redirect to the Previous worked page.

```js
window.history.back();
```

or

```js
history.back();
```

It redirects to the previous page that we used to work. but when you want to redirect to the particular URL you can use that link in the href tag.

click [Here](https://html.com/anchors-links/) for Reference the link tags